# Child LinearLayouts not displaying properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have one `LinearLayout` - horizontal, and it has 3 vertical `LinearLayout`s in it.

I add `TextView`s to those `LinearLayout`s programmaticaly. This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hlkurva"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PadyFragment">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/cesky">


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pomlcka"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/latinsky"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like on Android Studio preview.
[[image: This is how it should look like, on preview it looks correct]]

However, when I run the app I get this:
[[image: The third Linear Layour is diplaying down]]

When I rotate screen, it persist. I tried different layout weights, I tried it different way with no layout weight, I tried everything I can but I never get 3 Linear Layouts displayed horizontal to each other how it looks like on the preview. I am really desperate, please help.

Comment: give all 3 weights of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like you've passed the wrong view id to a `findViewById()` call in your activity. Maybe something like this:

```
LinearLayout left = findViewById(R.id.cesky);
LinearLayout middle = findViewById(R.id.latinsky); // wrong id here
LinearLayout right = findViewById(R.id.latinsky);
```

Then, later when you add all the `-` characters to the `middle` column, you're *actually* adding them to the right column because you've accidentally assigned the wrong view to `middle`.

Comment: Oh my god, you are an absolute boss for me, I called the findViewById on the right view, but I was adding elements to the wrong view. Now it all makes sense. THANK you so much